# Preferred method of checking object's class in R

Tags: r, coding-style, typechecking

What is the preferred method of checking an object's class in R?

(1)

```
is.data.frame(df)
```

(2)

```
class(df) == 'data.frame'
```

(3)

```
'data.frame' %in% class(df)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I would say

```
inherits(df,"data.frame")
```

or

```
is(df,"data.frame")
```

among other things, #2 in your list can fail because (as you suggest in #3) `class(df)` can have length > 1. (`is.data.frame` is nice, but not all classes have `is.` methods: see `methods("is")`)

Comment: I don't get the generic comment, it *couldn't* have been generic (at least I can't think of a way for it to be generic that would make sense)

Answer (score 5):

For me it'd be:

```
is.data.frame(df)
```

Is a clearer option to use in conditions. Also, is the 'less code' option of the three, if that is important for you.