# Any reason to prefer is.character than class(object) == "character"?

Tags: r

I have a very simple question with R, 
is there any reason for me to prefer the usage of

```
 is.character(object)
```

than

```
 class(object) == "character"
```

in R.

or the other `is.class` functions.

Comment: Try that test on this: `xx <- "abc"; class(xx) <- c("character", "otherclass")`

Comment: Related: [Preferred method of checking object's class in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733500/preferred-method-of-checking-objects-class-in-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides the obvious readability and performance arguments, you should almost *never* test an object’s class via `class(foo) == "class"`, as you cannot rely on it giving the correct result.

As nrussell commented, the S3 class system supports “inheritance” via tagging objects with more than one class name. As soon as more than a single class name is present, this equality check will yield nonsense.

Instead, use either:

```
if (inherits(obj, 'class'))
    … action …
```

Or, if you explicitly want to perform an exact test, not an inheritance test (which should be exceedingly rare):

```
if (identical(class(obj), 'class'))
    … action …
```

Comment: @RichardScriven “all the time” being gratuitous hyperbole. ;-) I use it, like, all the time.

Comment: Just to nitpick, I'd say that `class(foo) == "class"` will always give the correct result, but that result is almost never what the programmer intended. For what you said, someone could think that the `class` function has bugs and/or gives random results.