# Distinguish between an empty list or an empty data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm working with an API that seems to be returning a malformed data. The API shoud return nested data frames, but also returns empty lists on occasion too:

```
column_name
<list>
<data.frame [1 × 5]>                
<data.frame [0 × 0]>                
<data.frame [0 × 0]>                
<list [0]>
...
```

After this step I want to use `unnest` to use the data in the nested data frames downstream. However, the empty lists stop this from happening. What I thought of doing is:

- (1) Test to see if the row entry is an empty list
- (2) If yes, convert to an empty data frame; if no, leave as is

However, my go-to approaches of testing for empty lists have fallen a bit flat, as a data frame is a list. Currently I'm thinking of on using `identical` or `all.equal` in conjunction with `dim` for the test. Namely if the dimensions of the entry are [1,1], then replace this entry with an empty data frame.

(I am wondering what happens in the case where I have a data frame with dimensions [1,1] but actually has data in it too...)

Is this most the most R way of doing this? I've seen this behavior from the API elsewhere, so I will need to use this functionality in multiple places.

NB I'm using the tidyverse, if that impacts answers.

Comment: What about `class(data.frame()) == "list"` and `class(list()) == "list"`

Comment: or `is.data.frame(list())` for your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's often easier to clean the data as soon as you get it from the API. Then everything that follows can rely on safe assumptions.

For this example, create a function that returns a consistently formatted `tbl` using the API's response. Every `tbl` will have the same columns, but some of them might be filled with `NA` if they weren't in the response.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

response_to_df <- function(id = NA_real_,
                           country = NA_character_,
                           wealth = NA_real_,
                           ... # Catch extra columns you don't want
                           ) {
  tibble(id = id, country = country, wealth = wealth)
}

prepare_response_df <- function(response) {
  do.call(response_to_df, response)
}

responses <- list(
  tibble(id = 1:2, country = c("US", "DE"), wealth = c(95, 84)),
  list(),
  tibble(id = 3)
)

tibble(res = responses) %>%
  mutate(nicer = lapply(res, prepare_response_df)) %>%
  unnest(nicer)
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      id country wealth
#   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
# 1     1 US          95
# 2     2 DE          84
# 3    NA NA          NA
# 4     3 NA          NA
```

Answer (score 1):

A dataframe is a special `list` but the class is `dataframe`. You can test for the class this way :

```
class(data.frame()) == "list"
> FALSE
class(list()) == "list"
> TRUE
```

Comment: It might work in this example but don't use `class( ... ) == ...` to check class membership in R! `length(class(...))` can be `>1` (e.g. `class(matrix())== c("matrix", "array")`). Use `inherits` or `is`. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733500/preferred-method-of-checking-objects-class-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `map` and `if`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)  
ir %>% mutate(data1=map(data, ~if(is.null(dim(.x))) data.frame() else .x)) %>% 
       unnest(data1)
```

Data: Providing copy-past reproducible data is always useful

```
ir <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest()
ir$data[[2]]<-list()
```